# Applying .upper() method on text in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I need to make all text of a particular custom  button uppercase. While this would not be a problem if it was used only a couple of times as I could just apply the .upper() method for each instance of that custom button, in this case it is used throughout the project and searching for and applying it to each instance is not optimal.

Is there a way to apply a method to text that is yet to be defined in kivy?

In kivy I would like it to be something like this:

```
<GroupButton@Button>:
    text: text.upper() if text is not None else ''
```

And in python it would still be defined normally with:

```
button = Factory.GroupButton()
layout.add_widget(button)
button.text = 'something to turn into uppercase'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it perhaps, using the `self` reference, like this:

```
<GroupButton@Button>:
    text: self.text.upper() if self.text is not None else ''
```

Comment: I have not tested it but I think you are creating an infinite loop

Comment: then it seems that the code that interprets .kv is intelligent to only update the properties if these change avoiding loops :-)

Comment: Yeah, they made it lazyproof enough :o)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! :)